# Permission denied in /tmp

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, tmp

`/tmp` folder has all permission:

```
drwxrwxrwt 28 root root 20480 Jan 24 03:14 /tmp
```

File `/tmp/test.txt` already exists, with permission 666, owned by user `test1`.

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 test1 test1 0 Jan 24 02:34 /tmp/test.txt
```

As user `test2`, I run `echo hello >> /tmp/test.txt`

```
bash: /tmp/test.txt: Permission denied
```

Even when I switch to `root`, I still can't append to that file. It seems like only the owner of the files in `/tmp` can modify its content regardless of the permission bit.

---

Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-27-generic
Architecture: x86-64

Comment: Check the file system: mount, df

Comment: How is the filesystem mounted? Is it part of the host? What happens if the owning user runs the command?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the owner runs it fine. The filesystem is mounted normally, I believe. Everything is under /

Comment: @GerardH.Pille should I type those commands and paste the result here?

Comment: @vcth4nh no, leave it, I've no experience with vmware.

Comment: Yes put the results into the question.

Comment: I updated the solution below. Didn't notice the sticky bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To anyone having the same problem in the future, `/tmp` is a [sticky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) folder by default, meaning only the file owner can modify it. Therefore, to change others' files, you must remove the sticky bit: `sudo chmod -t /tmp`. Note that you should turn it back on afterward: `sudo chmod +t /tmp`.

---

As suggested in comments, a better solution is that you can also create a new folder in `/tmp` to do the trick without touching the permissions on `/tmp`.

Comment: Doing this on a multi-user system would be less than ideal. Instead, create a directory under `/tmp` and do the whatever you need to do in there, without touching the permissions on `/tmp`.